# can I say "platform implements system" ? in computer science

Tags: system, computer-science, platform

Hello I'm interested in computer science.

when I develop using android platform, I have some curiosity..

In computer science or engineering, I understood that 'platform' may include hardware or software components to solve sets of problem and 'system' is abstract concept for some purposes.

I'm not sure that these are correct. but anyway;

I wonder the relationship between 'platform' and 'system'

'platform' implements 'system' ? or

'system' includes 'platform' ? or

'system' is equal to 'platform' ?

These questions may be nonsense, but I want to know it more specifically.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Platform is an abstraction for a very generic set of libraries, Operating system and hardware drivers that allow for a program to be run.
System on the other hand encompasses computer software and hardware.

Platform moslty refers to the Operating System(not always though). In that context you can say that a platform is a part of the system. With the advent of virtualization it is very difficult to classify, since several hardware components are "virtualized". But in general, system is not just a platform, it encompasses more.

Answer (score 0):

Platform is hardware, operating system, possibly framework. I'd think of a platform as something to build on, or run things on.

System is a generic term. Operating system, database management system, content management system, a computer, a piece of software, an software development methodology...all of these are systems.